# Java Library to Consume/Manipulate Sharepoint 2013 Rest OData XML Result

Tags: java, android, xml, rest, sharepoint

I have an android App that Consumes the SharePoint 2013 Rest Web Service and Query using OData.I need to display the data from SharePoint in this android app.

I try to display a SharePoint List Data.For example i need to get the data from a specific column in the List.The Results I get a complex XML.

Is there any good Java libraries to manipulate this complex XML result to a Simple Form (such Row/Column Tables or Entities) ?

OR

Is there any Java Libraries to display the SharePoint REST response in a better way(than complex xml)?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this library :

https://code.google.com/p/java-sharepoint-library/

Comment: Thanks.But I think This library uses SOAP and Its quite old. Is there any Java Library that uses SharePoint 2013 REST API feature?

Answer (score 0):

[JShare](http://www.independentsoft.de/jshare) - JShare is Java and Android API for Microsoft SharePoint 2013 and Office 365 / SharePoint Online.

Comment: Thanks.But I need a Open Source Library.