# Consuming REST services from sharepoint

Tags: rest

I am trying to consume Odata service from Sharepoint using REST API, but fail to get the result as a missing schema ref

This is the error I got when putting the schema in VS

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata is not available to be referenced in this schema.
```

Can anyone help me to get these type of schemas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730475/java-library-to-consume-manipulate-sharepoint-2013-rest-odata-xml-result/24731856#24731856